# How to rebind drag and drop events when proceduarly rebuilding from a DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I've been using jQuery to create a drag and drop form builder. It's working great, except for when I try and rebuild it using the values from the database.

What I'm doing is creating a form builder that is based on accordions - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmklL.png image for reference.

Once you drag an accordion from the side to the droppable area, it expands and then becomes an element that other items can be dropped in to.

I store this data in the DB and have a form. Now if I want to load the form from pre-saved data the events aren't bound, what is the best way to rebind these events?

An example of my event binding process is like this.

```js
$(".mainDrop").droppable({
  accept: '.accordian',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (!$(ui.draggable).hasClass('item')) {
      console.log(ui);
      
      $(ui.draggable).addClass("item");
      $(ui.draggable).addClass("droppableAccord item");
      
      $(ui.draggable).css({
        'min-height': '300px'
      });
      
      $(ui.draggable).append(deleteButton);
      $(ui.draggable).append('<div class="accordArea sortableItem"></div>');
      
      $(".sortableItem").sortable({
        revert: 10
      });
      
      $(".accordArea").droppable({
        accept: assets.join(', '),
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          if (!$(ui.draggable).hasClass('item')) {
            console.log('dropped');

            if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('textfield')) {
              $(ui.draggable).html(textButton);
            } else if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('dropdown')) {
              $(ui.draggable).html(dropdownButton);
            } else if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('radio')) {
              $(ui.draggable).html(radioButton);
            } else if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('checkbox')) {
              $(ui.draggable).html(checkboxButton);
            } else if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('statictext')) {
              $(ui.draggable).html(statictextButton);
            } else if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('customcode')) {
              $(ui.draggable).html(customcode);
            }

            $(ui.draggable).append(deleteButton);
            $(ui.draggable).addClass("item");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code is very confusing to read, it seems to be doing operations that don't really make any sense. Next time, please try to make a minimal representation of the issue with nicely formatted code :)

Comment: There also isn't really enough details here deal with the issue. Can you add a link to a jsfiddle or something like that to see a demo of the issue? Or just try to give a more clear example of the issue in general.